# Graph API for Azure Identity Risk Events Not Pulling All Events

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to get emails whenever a risk event occurs in Azure AD.  We are a very large tenant, and they occur often.  I found this article from Microsoft and followed the steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/graph-get-started  However, I see that it is returning less than half the results that I see on the web interface.

I have copied and pasted the example code, filling in my tenant information, but I only get some results. (This is my first use of Graph API.)  We don't close the events, so I am receiving active events from Graph, and there are plenty of active events not coming through Graph.

I am using this URL: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityRiskEvents"
Here is how I save all the results to a variable:

```
$myReport = (Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Headers $headerParams -Uri $url)
$events = ($myReport.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).value
```

E.g. On the website, I have four (active) leaked credential events from 4/4/2019 to today, but in the Graph results, I only have one.
On the website, I have twelve (active) impossible travel events, but in the Graph I only have four in the same time span.

Do I need to close the events on the website to get the proper results, I wonder?

Comment: Have you tried calling the same api from graph api explorer : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#, Please try hitting IdentityRiskEvent api from explorer and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Meanwhile let me check with the concerned engineer and will get back to you.

Comment: It's the same results from the Graph API explorer. Thank you.

Comment: This week, I pulled Leaked Credential Events from the last seven days. On Graph, there was only one. On the Azure website, there were 14 (some accounts showed up more than once) in the last seven days.

Comment: I still in a discussion with the engineer, trying to repro .will update you

Answer (score 1):

When there are more risk events than the page size , you need to use pagination to query the data page by page by using OData $top and $skip. For example, the following queries return the page1, page2 and page3:

- GET  ~/beta/identityRiskEvents?$top=100
- GET  ~/beta/identityRiskEvents?$top=100&$skip=100
- GET  ~/beta/identityRiskEvents?$top=100&$skip=200

To avoid deep pagination, there is a limit of the pages to skip. So to query a big number of risk events you can add filters to separate the data into some chunks to query, for example:

GET ~beta/identityRiskEvents?$filter=riskLevel eq microsoft.graph.riskLevel'medium' and riskEventDateTime gt 2016-04-05T00:00:56.2255665Z&$count=true

If you're interested in a specific type of risk event, say leakedCredentials risk events, they can do the following queries:

GET  ~/beta/leakedCredentialsRiskEvents

Or

GET  ~/beta/identityRiskEvents?$filter=riskType eq ‘LeakedCredentialsRiskEvent’